# MySQL Monitoring Notificaation System

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, notifications

I'm building an APP with a website linked to a MySQL Online Database (OVH). Everything connects and works perfectly, but my knowledge on MySQL/PHP is limited.

I would like to create some kind of Notification that tells me when a new id is created in my database. Basically, when I have a new user account on my website.

I don't really know what do I need: a PHP page that refresh constantly the database ? A trigger that sends me a Notification by E-mail ? I'm looking for quick and simple solution to get notified when I have a new user on my MySQL database.

[This is my Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2SFY.png)

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0):

You can add a email notification in your "Register" function , so whenever user registers on your website you will get notified.

Use php mail() function to get e-mails.

```
<?php
// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// send email
mail("your@email.com","New User Registered",$msg);
?>
```